# CSS scale transform uses CPU for repaint

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I have to scale a div up and down with very fast rate (using GPU), but all browsers, except Safari, try to "improve" visual quality with CPU repaint. But it is very slow for my task that it should work even on very cheap Android Phones.

I have made a sample:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
}
.scaled {
    transform: translateZ(0px) translate(0px, 30px) scale(10, 10);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

<div>FUUUU</div>
<div class="scaled">FUUUU</div>
```

Safari (correct, GPU):

[image: Safari (correct, GPU)]

Firefox (incorrect, CPU):

[image: Firefox (incorrect, CPU)]

How can I prevent CPU repainting?

ADD: Text is just an example, it is pretty complex div box, which is slow on repaint.

Comment: you want to disable font smoothing?

Comment: No, text is just an example. I have a pretty complex box with images and text (user profile), which is repainted on scale animation even on slow Android devices browser (works fast and good on iOS/Safari)

Comment: I might be completely wrong in understanding your issue. But can't you use a canvas for this? Do you _need_ the DOM?

Comment: If nothing helps, I will use canvas (or even WebGL), but DOM much simple to layout my actual box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the point of your screenshots, but will answer anyway:

Simply, you cannot. As long as you are programming a webpage and not the internet browsers themselves, you cannot modify that kind of behaviour.

AFAIK, Mozilla Firefox is working to also start using the GPU for such processes and will be launched in September 2017 with the new engine (Firefox 57). I don't know about Chrome/Chromium or others.

---

Well, actually there is another option: Get the code and program a new internet browser with that feature by yourself, both Firefox and Chromium are open source.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I hoped that "translateZ(0px)" will be enough to browser "hey, just use GPU with current object", but it is strangely not.

Comment: Even back in 2017, using `translate3d` instead of `translateZ` would likely have mean different results. Translate3d almost always will use GPU, even for (0,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally realized that it is NOT using CPU, but GPU-only with hardware accelerated rasterization enabled.